# A nineties/possibly early 2000s Fantasy series

Tags: story-identification, magic, dragons

Cannot for the life of me think of the name of what I’m pretty sure was a three book series, here’s what I can remember:

There’s a barbarian invasion of some more civilised nations, a few of the civilised cities have colleges of magic. Magic users are called mages and in desperation one city summons a barrier of demons to surround themselves and have to sacrifice people to it every day to keep it up, this makes the demons so strong they can no longer be controlled.

There’s also dragons who are actually in an alternate dimension/plane/whatever and humans meet and talk to them at some sort of inter dimensional crossroads, the dragons are really angry about the demons thing. The main characters convince a few of the dragons to come help them and they cross in to the main world through a portal tunnel they have to defend from demons, the dragons are trapped there at the series end because the portal shuts.

One of the main characters finishes the book defending the dragons from would be poachers.

I’m afraid that’s about all I’ve got, I know it ain’t much but I’d appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a lot like James Barclay's *Chronicles of the Raven* followed by *Legend of the Ravens* series: https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/james-barclay/

It follows a group of elite mercenaries called the Ravens, on a continent named Balaia torn by a war between a barbarian horde coming from the West and a civilized East dominated by four rivals college of magic. Initially, they are tasked with escorting a wizard who looks for a devastating spell called the DawnThief that could change the war, before the barbarian shamans find it.

The storyline with the dragons from another dimension happens in book 2 *NoonShade* (after the DawnThief spell misfired and opened a tear between realities) and the grisly demonic barrier thing happens in book 5 (*ShadowHeart*) or 6 (*DemonStorm*), I'm not sure. The dragons then come back to help fight a Demon invasion caused by all the magic energy released since the colleges went at war with each others (with the barbarian menace still in the background)

Comment: Can you include some details about these books that show how it matches?  As it is you haven't even linked directly to any of these books, and even if there is some useful info there it will disappear if the link ever breaks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_the_Raven is a more direct link.